# Where can I view badges I've earned?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

I noticed that I've occasionally been getting badges (seems like a local version of achievements for this game). Unfortunately, while mashing A to get through victory screens, I sometimes blow through the popup that tells me what I earned and I'm unable to see what it was. I haven't been able to find how to view these badges after earning them, but I assume there's a way to do so. How do I view them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exhausting all my options, it appears that the awards you've earned are displayed on the bottom screen if you hit `Connect` > `Profile Card`. Tapping on each award will explain what you did to earn it.